# Gradient of four co-ordinates? (Plane)

Tags: math, gradient, java-3d, plane

Lets say I have a plane, with the four co-ordinates:

```
(0,0,0)
(0,0,1)
(1,2,0)
(1,2,1)
```

So it's a basic plane with a gradient of 2 in x axis and 0 in the others? -I can figure that out just by plotting/looking at it.

How could I work the gradient out of any given (assuming four co-ords form a flat surface) plane?

I'm very confused when it comes to vectors/matrix's/co-ords/transformations etc... But I need to know the gradient of planes for a java3d project I'm making.

Comment: In general, four points don't form a plane.

Comment: Ok well I mean like a quadrilateral then, didn't know there was a difference.

Comment: I mean that in the general case, 4 points don't form a flat surface.  Therefore, to talk about a gradient is meaningless.

Comment: Oh, well i'm assuming they will, i'll edit OP thanks.

Comment: You will also need to define what you mean by "gradient".  If I give you (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (1,0,1), (0,0,1), what is the gradient?

Comment: A plane if formed by 3 points.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I think you're confused about what a gradient is. If I'm thinking of the correct definition of gradient, then you can only take the gradient of a function. In other words let **`f:R^3 -> R`**, **`grad(f) = (df/dx,df/dy,df/dz)`**.  So, you can't exactly take the gradient of a plane, because a plan in general is not a function. However, a plane can be expressed as a two-variable function, and you can take the gradient of that.  A plane is every linear combination of two vectors, in this case **`(0,0,1)`** and **`(1,2,0)`**, which you would write as:
**`f:R^2 -> R^3`**, **`f(u,v) = u*(0,0,1) + v*(1,2,0)`**.  To find the vectors multiplied to u and v, just choose three of those four points such that the three you choose are not colinear, and find a vector from the first to the second and from the first to the third. Since you now have your plane expressed as a function, you can take the gradient.

Comment: Indeed.  But this is not unique; there are an infinite number of possible basis-vector pairs.

Comment: True, but he only needs one for each plane. This is why I don't understand his question. I believe you take the gradient of a function, and the function for a plane is not unique, so the gradient is not unique.

Comment: I agree.  I don't think his question is well-formed.